# I am having trouble linking two pages in Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, html, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am following an tutorial on Pluralsight to build a web app and I am getting an error connecting `team.html` and `team-detail.html`. What does `"ui-sref = "app.game({id: game.gameId}"` on Line 4 of `team-detail.html` do? Is it correct? 
My error says:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
  at new TeamDetailCtrl (team-detail-ctrl.js:18)
  at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:11994)
  at extend.instance (ionic.bundle.js:16247)
  at ionic.bundle.js:15502
  at forEach (ionic.bundle.js:8155)
  at nodeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:15501)
  at compositeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:14887)
  at publicLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:14766)
  at self.appendViewElement (ionic.bundle.js:47324)
  at Object.switcher.render (ionic.bundle.js:45864)ionic.bundle.js:19387 (anonymous function)
```

Here's a link to the code I have halfway through the tutorial:
https://github.com/bhaskar2khaneja/EliteScheduleApp/tree/master/www

Also, I do not understand what `<.. href = "#/app/teams/{{team.id}}">` is doing in the `standings.html` file. It's not producing the output I am expecting on clicking different items in the file.

Here's the data the app is using: http://elite-schedule.net/api/leaguedata/2009

Comment: `vm.teamName = team.name` is failing because `team` is undefined.  That is, `var team = _.chain(data.teams)...` is not giving you the value you're expecting.  I'd look there.

Comment: Why is team undefined though? The tutorial does not give an elaborate description of the methods in underscore.js and I am a beginner, so I can't really make out.

Comment: Could be a couple of things... Is `vm.teamId = Number($stateParams.id)` properly setting `vm.teamId` to a number?

Comment: Have you created [this](https://github.com/bhaskar2khaneja/EliteScheduleApp/blob/4eb6bee31b9f6a7330ced109263537a63dd8757c/www/app/services/eliteApi.js) factory, as well?

Comment: I am not sure but this is exactly what the person in the tutorial is using, and it's working fine.

Comment: Yes. Just that the person had another variable league storing some different data as well (that I couldn't find when I tried using the data).